# Google Sheet - Move row on Sheet 2 to Sheet 3 if Sheet 1 says yes

Tags: javascript, worksheet-function

I need some help with this script

```
function issueComplete() {
  var sheetNameToWatch = "ISSUES"; 
  var columnNumberToWatch = 11;
  var valueToWatch = "YES";
  var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "ARCHIVE";
  var finalSheet = "ISSUE_ARCHIVE";

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName(finalSheet);

  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();
  if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {

  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
  var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 2);
  sheet2.getRange(range.getRow(), 2, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
  sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
  sheet2.deleteRow(range.getRow());
  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow(); 
  sheet.insertRows(lastrow, 1);
  }
}
```

Now more about what I need help with,

I am using 3 sheets in total

[Sheet1 (Sheet to be edited)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNdsV.jpg)
[Sheet2 (With the information)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XupdL.jpg)
Sheet3 (Destination - Exact same layout as Sheet2)

The user is to be using sheet 1 and when they select YES from the drop down menu in column J, it is to send that row value on sheet 2 to sheet 3 and then  delete the rows on sheet1 & sheet2 and add new replacement rows.

I have a similar version to the code above which works great if I want info from the active sheet to be moved to another, but not when it involves 3!

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I have found a solution, however if anyone feels it can be improved in anyway please let me know!

```
function issueComplete() {
Utilities.sleep(200);

var sheetNameToWatch = "ISSUES"; 
var columnNumberToWatch = 10;
var valueToWatch = "COMPLETED";
var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "ARCHIVE";

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getActiveCell(); // what cell changed?
if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {

var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 2); 

var infoSheet = ss.getSheetByName("ISSUE_ARCHIVE")

infoSheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 2, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange); 

var formulas = range.getFormulas(); 
range.clearContent();
range.setFormulas(formulas);

infoSheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
}
}
```